# MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT don't throw mysqli_sql_exception ,but MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL does

Tags: php, mysqli, report, strict

I had set

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)
```

and

```
try{
   //query sth ,error will happend
 }catch(Exception $e){   print($e->__toString());       }
```

but there is no debug info . but If I set `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` ,I can get the debug info. why?

Comment: What particular debug info you expect?

Comment: mysqli_sql_exception is what I wanted. when I use MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL,I can catch the exception,but when I use MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT ,I can' catch the exception

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable the error reporting (`MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR`) if it is not already (depending on the version of PHP this is either per-request or per-process). By itself, `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` does not enable the error reporting, the appropriate bitwise flags might need to be applied together:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had tried this way .it is the same as mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)

Comment: @user2407743 Yes it is same but different way!

Comment: @user2407743 are you gettig exceptios in using `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL`.can you post your logs here

Comment: ---the follow is MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL 's debug output---
exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Unknown column 'uidx' in 'where clause'' in /var/www/html/bc/1.0.4/user.php:906
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/bc/1.0.4/user.php(906): mysqli->query('update bcuser s...')
#1 /var/www/html/bc/1.0.4/user.php(1027): user->login('1')
#2 /var/www/html/bc/1.0.4/user.php(1036): main()
#3 {main}{"resp":"none"}